# Spring MVC Session Max lifetime

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session, spring-security

I'm aware we can `session.setMaxInactiveInterval(1200);` to set session expiry time on inactivity. I've a requirement like the user session should get expire at a given point of time.

For instance if a user is configured to access from 9AM-9PM, it should get forced logout at 9PM.

Is there any function like `session.maxLife(1200);` or any other solution to achieve this?

Comment: If I understand, you want to expire session in specific time?

Comment: @Hrabosch Either at a specific time or after a specific interval; whichever is feasible

Comment: So, I dont know about anything how you could achieve that. But maybe you could set session timeout always by setting lifetime by computing at certain time. I mean something like Session is created now, so check what is time, compute a lifetime from that. But I never tried it! Just idea now.

Comment: I can handle the login part. Just need to forcefully logout the user once the  specific time is over. For instance first request after 9PM should force logout.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to achieve can be done through interceptors. Only the difference being that instead of deciding the life span initially, you block/allow a request dynamically after analyzing session. Different methods available in session are listed in http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html.

You can set custom attributes for every session, like accessStartTime, accessEndTime and read them every-time in interceptor for all requests. If the current time is not in the range of user access time period, then you can call invalidate on the session object.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However I was looking for a solution without interceptors/filters. I want to make use of any built-in feature in spring, avoiding the overhead of this check on every request